# Python - Using string as condition in if statement

Tags: python, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to do this:

```
a = "1 or 0"
if (a): Print "true"
```

So I can use a string as the condition of an if statement. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but it's strongly discouraged. It would be better to change your code to avoid this.

Comment: @Volatility Discouraged by whom? Not by PEP-8 which says "For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false."

Comment: @Anonymous: The string is valid Python code (which I think is intentional), so I think OP is basically asking "can I treat this string as code and evaluate it", which is what `eval` is for.

Comment: @Anonymous I think you've missed the point of the question. I was talking about having code which means you have to use `eval`.

Answer (score 11):

It's possible, but don't do it:

```
a = '1 or 0'

if eval(a):
    print 'a is True'
```

`eval()` is hard to debug, offers no benefit here and is easily exploitable if you allow arbitrary user input (e.g. `a = "__import__('os').system('rm -Rf /')"`).

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: I read the question as "if a = 1 or 0" and assumed that they forgot the comparison ==. But your answer makes more sense

Answer (score 3):

You could combine the string "a == " with your input string and [eval()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) it. You should do this  carefully, because you are allowing arbitrary code to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

A string will always be `True` for the `if` statement `if it is not empty`, so it is of no use to use it in the `if` statement.

```
In [12]: my_str = 'a=a'

In [13]: if my_str:
   ....:     print True
   ....: else:
   ....:     print False
   ....:     
True

In [14]: new_str = ''

In [15]: if new_str:
   ....:     print True
   ....: else:
   ....:     print False
   ....:     
False

In [16]:
```

So Try to pass some real condition that computes to be a boolean.